# How to click on this button on Webpage using Perl and Mechanize

Tags: javascript, perl, firefox, button, mechanize

This may sound very simple to expirenced Perl Scripters, but I'm trying to click on a button on a webpage using Perl and the `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` from CPAN. Here is the source code for the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="add-to-cart nsg-button--nike-orange" >

                        ADD TO CART

        </button>
```

This is not the only button on the page by the way, my current method of trying to click on it is `click_button => 'ADD TO CART'` but that does not seem to be working for me. **Any help on clicking this button is greatly needed**. Thank you.

Comment: `click_button` accepts the `name` of the button, the `value` of the button, button object, the `id` of the button, or the button number. `ADD TO CART` is none of those.

Comment: It does not like valid HTML for me.

Comment: If add to cart is none of those then now should I click the button?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `$mech->click({ selector => '.add_to_cart' });`according to the documentation.